# Trying to synchronize the clock timing of two computers

Tags: ubuntu, clock, ntp

I am trying to synchronize the clock timing of two different computers. They are both connected to server and located next to each other.

At first, I went to the /etc/ntp.conf file. I saw the following four lines in each computers' file:

server 0.ubuntu.pool.ntp.org
...................
server 3.ubuntu.pool.ntp.org

Then I typed "ntpq -p" and I found that they are getting times from different servers! They were showing different clock times, too. Therefore, I typed "sudo vi /etc/ntp.conf" and then took out the NTP Pool Project servers. Now, both computers are using Ubuntu's ntp server as a fallback. They only have the following line (the other server lines are commented):

server ntp.ubuntu.com

However, they still show a couple of seconds' drift. Did I do the correct steps?

How can I time synchronize these computers?

Thanks,

Nazmul

Answer (score 0):

ComputerA (A) and ComputerB (B) where showing different remote time servers because the ntp pool project combines a lot of different ntp servers. There is nothing wrong with the A and B synchronizing to different pool hosts. When you say "different clock times too" you realize that the difference in time was in milliseconds.

Do you really need time sub millisecond accuracy?

If not (and I assume not) you should go back to the initial ntpd configuration using the ubuntu pool servers. If you wanted to you could change:

```
server 1.ubuntu.pool.ntp.org
```

to

```
server 1.CC.pool.ntp.org
```

Where CC is your country code, eg us,uk,dk,ca. More information about country codes can be found on the ntp pool project site: http://www.pool.ntp.org/en/

PS

For even better results use iburst:

```
server 1.CC.pool.ntp.org iburst
```